# GUI freeze while loading data in BackgroundWorker

Tags: .net, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a `ListView` control receiving data from `BackgroundWorker` through `ReportProgress`. The worker dumps about a hundred rows in a quick succession. Each chunk of data fires `ProgressChanged` event and GUI thread adds a new item to the `ListView`.

As the data retrieval operations run on a separate thread, the GUI is supposed to update on every change. But for some reason it doesn't happen - the interface remains frozen until the worker is completed.

Any ideas?

Also, the tests are done on very fast machine, so I don't think computer performance is an issue.

It's a WinForms application.

Comment: Also mention WPF or windows forms.

Comment: WinForms. The code doesn't have anything specific - simply Worker.ReportProgress(25, newItem) and ListView1.Items.Add(item.DisplayName).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your BGW worker loop, after the ReportProgress call:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
```

Odds are good that you now see the ListView updating.  What's going on here is that the UI thread is getting flooded with delegate invoke requests.  Which always get dispatched before the paint notification.  If the *next* invoke request arrives before the previous one has finished running then it never gets around to doing the normal housekeeping tasks.  Like painting and responding to input.  The items actually do get added to the list view, you just can't see it being done.

Call ReportProgress less often.  Doing it more than 25 times per second is a waste of resources, no human can see the difference.  Let the BGW store the items in a List<> and cut down on the UI thread overhead by calling AddRange().

Comment: That works. But the process depends on PC performance now - on a slow machine delay needs to be higher. Is there any performance-independent way? I thought maybe Application.DoEvents would help in waiting while the housekeeping is done, but getting StackOverflowException (huh) now.

Comment: 25 times per second is the human number, quite good enough for any machine.  Don't call ReportProgress until at least 40 msec has passed.  DateTime.Now works fine to measure that, you'll get ~21 updates per second.

Comment: I just took this code out of a form I wrote about a year ago thinking, "Why on earth would I sleep it here??" Reading your answer to this question I'm reminded of why I did it in the first place. "Oooooooh, right. It needs time to catch up from the last ProgressChanged event."

Answer (score 1):

You could try batch loading items into ListView1.Items using AddRange instead of Add. Just fill an intermediate array and use with AddRange.

Comment: The main point of this is to show data to the user without waiting for the whole load to complete.

Comment: @Sphynx - I was thinking of numerous small batches. Winforms listview performance isn't great in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a row one by one in a `ListView` will cause a freeze even on fast machines.

Try calling `ListView.SuspendLayout()` and `ListView.ResumeLayout()` before and after the population process.

Comment: Just tried that - doesn't seem to help. I've seen many programs doing this - they load a standard ListView on another thread and it updates on every change.