# BackgroundWorker in VS2010 doesn't run in another thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I created a WinForm in Visual Studio 2010 (c++), almost the same as this example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waw3xexc.aspx

but when I click on the button that "lunch" the BackgroundWorker it "stucks" the WinForm,
so I can't move it or click on "stop button" for the time the function runs.

The function runs as desired - is returns the expected result, and also the progress bar is ok.
It seems that the BackgroundWorker runs in the same thread as the WinForm.

What might be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So the event handler of the "launch" button calls RunWorkerAsync of a BackgroundWorker and do nothing else?

Comment: yes, it calls RunWorkerAsync and does some enabeling and un-enabeling of buttons

Comment: When you debug, does the main thread completely run though the event handler?

Comment: I don't understand the question. how can I check it?

Comment: The main thread - the form, is stil shown, but I cant click on buttons or move it while the function us running.

Comment: When you step through the code, inside the event handler, does it reach the ending bracket?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Thomas. I found the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [GUI freeze while loading data in BackgroundWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944051/gui-freeze-while-loading-data-in-backgroundworker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The BackgroundWorker actually runs on another thread but it send Events of **update progress** too often and those events "lunch" function in the main form - that updates ProgressBar - and this funcion "stucks" the form.